# Web2py client server not working

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to run a project which holds data in web2py server and web2py based client shows the visualization. When running both server and client , the chrome console on clinet side shows:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8075/?format=json. 
No 'Access-Control-     Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
[ERROR] Cannot connect to data server:  http://127.0.0.1:8075?format=json
```

I'm running above with web2py2.9.5 on linux.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your web2py client page is served on port 8080 but is then making an Ajax request to port 8075, which violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) enforced by web browsers.

If you can't serve both from the same origin, you can get around this by using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or by setting up [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).